# On Android 11 or higher - How to change the style or the height of the dialog for the MediaStore.createTrashRequest?

Tags: android, delete-file, android-pendingintent, mediastore

When deleting files - my app need to ask the system for a deletion dialog using the "MediaStore.createTrashRequest"
It works fine on portrait mode but on landscape - the dialog is too big and the "approve" button is hidden.

If I use the other "MediaStore.createDeleteRequest"(no recycle bin) option -> the text is shorter and the button appears.

I have tried changing dialog style in the theme -> it had no effect.
I guess that I need to style the height of the dialog for the MediaStore.createTrashRequest ? how - this dialog is not created by my app but the o.s.

If I select 2 files - the dialog that the createTrashRequest creates uses several small thumbnails instead of the big one and so - the button appears.

I am using "Material Design".

```
 PendingIntent pi = MediaStore.createTrashRequest(mContext.getContentResolver(), array_list, true);
 IntentSender sender = pi.getIntentSender();
 if (sender != null)
    startIntentSenderForResult(sender, REQUEST_PERM_DELETE, null, 0, 0, 0, null);
```

[image]

Comment: Which phone are you using?

Comment: I have Pixel 6.

Comment: That's weird, cause I have the same device and I am not facing any system dialogs related issues.